# CentOS 7 won't boot after `yum update`

Tags: centos, boot

I just set up a fresh install of CentOS 7.2, and after doing `yum update`, I can not boot into my machine. The kernel was updated, I can see both kernels in GRUB2, but I cannot boot into either of them, I cannot even boot into the rescue kernel. When I do the monitor goes black and does not come back, or stalls during boot and won't respond to any key presses. I think I forgot to do a `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg` possibly? Any advice?

Edit: single user works for original kernel. But if I try single user with new kernel the monitor goes black. I must have gotten a bad nouveau driver or something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- get a rescue image on a usb stick or cd
- try nomodeset kernel arg (or try removing it)
- can you boot into single user mode? (stick 'single' on the end of the kernel args)

Comment: I can get into single user for the old kernel. Not the new kernel

Comment: And, when I switch to graphical mode that is when it stops working. I will see if I can `yum history undo $everything`

Comment: Nomodeset seems to work. I guess there is an issue with xorg or gdm?

Comment: Actually, the opposite is true. Nomodeset tells the kernel not to try and use the video driver directly.  With nomodeset, the kernel uses a generic video driver.  The only time that should really be a problem is when you want a super snazy 4K splash screen during bootup, or something.  Otherwise once you get X working, you shouldn't notice.

Answer (score -2):

If grub boot is causing you problems, then open rescue kernel

```
yum remove kernel.....(new one)
yum update (now your new kernel should work fine)
```

Comment: "I cannot even boot into the rescue kernel" - From the question.